# Keyboard shortcut within Mission Control for choosing a specific application window?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control

I use Mountain Lion and want to know if there are keyboard shortcuts for moving around and choosing a particular application window **within** a given active desktop in Mission Control.

I chose an option to show all active windows separately in Mission Control.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Related question at Super User: [How to make Mission Control keyboard friendly?](http://superuser.com/questions/313055/how-to-make-mission-control-keyboard-friendly) ... unfortunately, there doesn't yet appear to be a way to select a particular application using only the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you REALLY use Mission Control a lot there IS a workaround that must be configured individually:

[EDIT:] I wrote an "elaborate" Karabiner Elements script (json); it's linked at the bottom of this post.

The very commendable 3rd party software "Karabiner Elements" (interim version) allows to simulate mouse movements in a "general" way, meaning: no exact positioning to screen coordinates, but just movements to left/right/bottom/top (or combinations of these).

Moreover its "mouse moves" depend on your System-Preferences' mouse velocity settings.
But still, if you invest a little time for finding ideal values for your own mouse, you'll be rewarded by a shortcut "script" that allows to (e.g.:) move between visible apps' windows through arrow-key-directing.

A typical code particle looks like this:
`{"mouse_key": {"x": 3072}` which moves a mouse cursor "fast" to right, "y" values moving up/down ("3072" = max. value; depending on your mouse settings one click would "call" this code several times).

Here `arrow keys` move cursor, `return/enter` take a selected window back to your space.

An over-simplified "script" would look like this:

```
{"title": "Mission control, navigation",
 "rules":[
            {"description": "Mission control, navigation",
             "manipulators": [
                   { "from": { "key_code": "right_arrow"},
                       "to": [ {"mouse_key": {"x": 3072}} ],
                     "type": "basic" },
                   { "from": { "key_code": "left_arrow"},
                       "to": [ {"mouse_key": {"x": -3072}} ],
                     "type": "basic" },
                   { "from": { "key_code": "down_arrow"},
                       "to": [ {"mouse_key": {"y": 3072}} ],
                     "type": "basic" },
                   { "from": { "key_code": "up_arrow"},
                       "to": [ {"mouse_key": {"y": -3072}} ],
                     "type": "basic" },
                   { "from": { "key_code": "return_or_enter"},
                       "to": [ {"pointing_button": "button1"} ],
                     "type": "basic"     } ]
}        ]  }
```

*As mentioned: this code lacks essential ingredients, is even **dangerous**:

E.g., in **every app** you use a "return" or "enter" would be replaced by a **mouse click**!*

So firstly: it is *NOT restricted* to the "Mission Control" view; reason is: *there is no actual app to aim at!* … MC's "frontmost_application" is the top one in "normal" view, e.g. Finder or Safari.
This *MUST* be handled by calling "mandatory" modifiers (I recommend/use: `Control & Shift`).

Next: above, you have to *keep arrow keys pressed* while the cursor "rolls" across your screen.
This is improved by making "multiple" (= farther) "jumps" in one key press *AND* preventing key repetitions.
About 4 to 8 "moves" (= times "arrow" pressed) to get from one end of your screen to the other seems practical to me; the return key will select an app's window and "go back".

I installed a much more elaborated code version on my MacBook-Air – and it works quite nicely.
<strike>Maybe, if somebody's interested, I'll post a json file here, once I optimised  all facets of it …</strike>
Here is my code for a "realistic" mouse jump behaviour:

https://gist.github.com/clemsam/ef03ed5127fd9783267b60065c70fc17